# C++ provide only undeducable template types

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++20, ctad

Assume we have class that depends on two template types one of we specialize in constructor, can we not specialize deducable type?

```
template <typename T, typename I>
class A {
public:
    A(I i) {

    }
};

int main() {
    A<float, int> a(42); // this works, but we can deduce int from 42

    A<float> aa(42); // doesn't work
    //or
    auto aaa = A<float>(42); // doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++20, you can use alias template deduction like this:

```cpp
template <typename I>
using A_float = A<float, I>;

int main() {
    A_float a(42);
    auto aa = A_float(42);
}
```

Try it on godbolt.org: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yhd8zx).

Alternatively, you can define a `make` function and deduce `I` from the function parameter. Because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), this is no less efficient than constructing the `A` directly:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename I>
auto make_a(I i) { return A<T, I>(i); }

int main() {
    auto a = make_a<float>(42);
}
```

Try it on godbolt.org: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cPTjfG).

Comment: No way to do it without adding new template type?

Comment: or at least in more generic way, so I won't create a new using for each case

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo do you need `typename I` anywhere else in the class besides the constructor?

Comment: yeah, I'll have member of this type

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo I've updated my answer.